# Wordpress SMTP not sending not working on other domains

Tags: wordpress, smtp

I need your help!

My main website is in german, and I used WPML to translate it into french and english.
Contact form 7 is working properly, it sends emails after submit but only if the form is on the german page, if I try to use it on the french or english page it doesn't work.
Any idea how to deal with it?
I use WP Mail SMTP Wordpress Plugin.

Comment: Check the transalation for Contact Form 7, You might be missing data in your other languages on CF7.